# Environment variables in Jenkins after service hook from TFS

Tags: git, jenkins, tfs, jenkins-pipeline

I'm building in Jenkins and I'm triggering the builds via a service hook from TFS.
The service hook triggers when a pull request merge commit is created and it triggers a generic build, the build is done via a Jenkins pipeline (jenkinsfile).

The service hook works as I can see the build being triggered, but there's some information that I'd like access to and I'm not sure if it's possible.

I was wondering if we could access the pull request ID or the target merge branch or the URL of the pull request?

I have the TFS plugin installed on Jenkins but I don't think the build environment variables can provide any of the above.

I can see that the request from the service hook looks like this:

```
Method: POST
URI: http://dirf-jenkins.dirf.com:8080/job/PR DataCollection Pipeline/build
HTTP Version: 1.1
Headers:
{
  Authorization: Basic ********
  Jenkins-Crumb: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
}
Content:
pullRequestId=34&commitId=37082f927fbc66692451c49886629e5fb67cd081
```

I can see that it passes the pull request ID - is there any way to get this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you are building in Jenkins, the TFS build variables will not be available.

You can try to call the [REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/git/pull-requests/pull-requests#by-repository-id) to get the information.